# I'm having trouble removing an item from localStorage for my tasklist app which i'm building using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Here's a function i'm having trouble with the foreach loop traverses just fine but i'm having trouble removing item from localStorage.

```
function removeFromLocalStorage(taskItem) {
  let tasks;
   if (localStorage.getItem("tasks") === null) {
      tasks = [];
   } else {
      tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
   }

   tasks.forEach((task, index) => {
      if (task === taskItem) {
      tasks = localStorage.removeItem(task);
      }
  });
  }
```

Comment: You appear to be storing a list of tasks in the key `tasks`. If you want to remove tasks, you need to remove them from *that list*, then stringify it again to JSON and overwrite `tasks`. As far as we can see, you’re not storing individual tasks in individual local storage keys.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
function removeFromLocalStorage(taskItem) {
     let tasks;
     if (localStorage.getItem("tasks") === null) {
        tasks = [];
     } else {
        tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
     }

     let result = tasks.filter(task => task != taskItem);
     localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(result));
  }
```

Comment: mark as answered if the answer is useful upvote will be bonus.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to remove an element in the array that you have stored in localstroage.

You have to remove the element from the array and then set it back

```js
function removeFromLocalStorage(taskItem) {
    // gets the array from the localstorage
    let tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks")) || [];
    // removing the taskItem by filter method and setting it back
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", tasks.filter(task => task !== taskItem));
}
```